# Can I save my Foobar2000 layout to disk?

Tags: foobar2000

I spent some time laying out my Foobar2000 installation, and want to be able to restore things to the same positions quickly on other machines or when reinstalling Windows.

Is there some file I can copy/replace that stores the layout information?

Answer (score 10):

Besides backing up `%AppData%\Foobar2000\Theme.fth`, you can also use the *Preferences / Default User Interface / Export Theme* option.

Answer (score 2):

Yes indeed you can :)

Your layout lives in

```
%appdata%\foobar2000
```

Copy everything in that directory and paste it in the same directory on the other machines to transfer layouts/settings.